# We read data from brokers through multiple consumers using consumer group, but how the consumed data is combined?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, consumer

I need data from kafka brokers,but for fast access I am using multiple consumers with same group id known as consumer groups.But after reading by each consumer,how can we combine data from multiple consumers? Is there any logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, different consumers in the same consumer group process data independently from each other.  (This behavior is what allows applications to scale well.)

> But after reading by each consumer,how can we combine data from multiple consumers? Is there any logic?

The short but slightly simplified answer when you use Kafka's "Consumer API" (also called: "consumer client" library), which I think is what you are using based on the wording of your question: If you need to combine data from multiple consumers, the easiest option is to make this (new) input data available in another Kafka topic, where you do the combining in a subsequent processing step.  A trivial example would be: the other, second Kafka topic would be set up to have just 1 partition, so any subsequent processing step would see all the data that needs to be combined.

If this sounds a bit too complicated, I'd suggest to use Kafka's Streams API, which makes it much easier to define such processing flows (e.g. joins or aggregations, like in your question).  In other words, Kafka Streams gives you a lot of the desired built-in "logic" that you are looking for: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/

Answer (score 1):

The aim of Kafka is to provide you with a scalable, performant and fault tolerant framework. Having a group of consumers reading the data from different partitions asynchronously allows you to archive first two goals. The grouping of the data is a bit outside the scope of standard Kafka flow - you can implement a single partition with single consumer in most simple case but I'm sure that is not what you want.

For such things as aggregation of the single state from different consumers I would recommend you to apply some solution designed specifically for such sort of goals. If you are working in terms of Hadoop, you can use Storm [Trident bolt](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.4/Trident-API-Overview.html) which allows you to aggregate the data from you Kafka spouts. Or you can use Spark Streaming which would allow you to do the same but in a bit different fashion. Or as an option you can always implement your custom component with such logic using standard Kafka libraries.